# Separate sass files for different responsive media queries/device sizes?

Tags: css, sass, media-queries

For organization is it wise to create separate sass files for different responsive media queries/devices, is that an overload?

Example: _small-phone.scss 
and place all small phone related styles within.

Is there any performance issues with this or its fine?

Thank you.

Comment: In my opinion it is not wise to split CSS files into parts respecting breakpoints. Most importantly not all CSS properties change between breakpoints, so in order to get an idea of what will be rendered without looking at rendered output, you would need to check many files, and that could cause an issue. Moreover `_small-phone.scss` is not self explanatory, while using exact value (i.e. `_800px.scss`) might cause an issues white debugging and changing breakpoints values.  In terms of performance it doesn't matter as long as files are imported properly.

Comment: okay, so style responsiveness within the same file don't create extra.. okay got it. Thank you.